# Modifies SQL DATA procedure called from inside a READS SQL DATA procedure

Tags: sql, inheritance, stored-procedures, db2-400

I am trying to define a generic SQL Error routine that will essentially dump all the information from `GET DIAGNOSTICS` to a file.

I have created a procedure that grabs all this info, and it works great when called from inside another procedure that `MODIFIES SQL`.  I also need it in the procedures where I fetch data. These procedures are defined with `READS SQL DATA` and when it calls the error routine, it fails because it inherits the caller's `READ`.

How can I avoid this issue. I would prefer not to change all my `READS SQL DATA` to `MODIFIES SQL DATA` as it can open up the data for modification and we do not want that.

Comment: "...it can open up the data for modification and we do not want that." And that is the reason that MODIFIES SQL DATA is restricted within READS SQL DATA. Allowing it would break the SQL 'contract' that guarantees that calling the outer proc won't cause unknown changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use native I/O in RPG or COBOL to write to the diagnostic data to the file?

Comment: That is what we ended up doing.  Would have rather used all SQL, but alas, needed native IO to perform the task.

Comment: Perhaps you could perform the native IO by writing an RPGOA handler which could execute SQL internally.